# how to remove leading zero from mysql column value in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

how to remove leading zero from MySQL column value in `codeigniter`.
which is use in where condition.Thanks in Advance

Query syntax is below,
`delivery_order_no` can be `0001`

```
$this->db->where("delivery_order_no","1");
```

Comment: What datatype is `delivery_order_no`? If it's `INT`, leading zeroes aren't part of the value.

Comment: Datatype of delivery_order_no is varchar(20)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **intval()** function

```
    $string= '0021';
$this->db->where("delivery_order_no",intval($string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `delivery_order_no` to an integer, that will remove leading zeroes.

```
$this->db->where("0 + delivery_order_no = $id");
```